# Assume we know that (1) $A$ reduces to $B$ in time $O(f(n))$ time and (2) $B$ reduces to $A$. What can we say about the time for $B$ -> $A$?

Tags: turing-machines, np-complete, reductions

The question is basically the title. If two NP-Complete problems reduce to each other, do we know that the reductions take equal amounts of time? What about space? Does this apply for all 'invertible' reductions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a positive answer, since it would imply $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$.
Indeed you can show that $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$ implies that the answer is "no" (and hence you have the contrapositive implication).

If $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$ then all problems within $P$, except for $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$, are $\mathsf{NP}$-complete and reduce to each other.
Consider now a finite language $A \in \mathsf{P} \setminus \{ \emptyset, \Sigma^* \}$ and and any language $B \in \mathsf{B}$ that can't be decided in constant time (e.g., "is the number of 0s" in the input even?").
Clearly $A$ can be reduced to $B$ in time $O(1)$, (check if the input is in $A$ in constant time, and return either a fixed yes-instance of $B$ or a fixed no-instance of $B$), but $B$ cannot be reduced to $A$ in the same time.

Perhaps somebody can point out a non-conditional argument for the answer being "no".

Comment: Ah, okay that makes sense. Thank you :)